# Turning object into array, and the multiply it by object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object `items = {a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3"}`.
I want to turn it into an array, but multiplied by `c`.
So if `items = {a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3"}` i want to get:

```
["arr brr","arr brr","arr brr"].
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.from()` to generate an array with the length of the value of `c`:

```js
const items = {a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3" }

const result = Array.from(
  { length: +items.c }, 
  () => `${items.a} ${items.b}`
)

console.log(result)
```

Use `Array.flatMap()` with `Array.from()` to handle an array of objects:

```js
const items = [{a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3" },{a:"ann", b:"bnn", c: "1" }]

const result = items.flatMap(obj => Array.from(
  { length: +obj.c }, 
  () => `${obj.a} ${obj.b}`
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: and if i have array of objects? [{a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3" },{a:"ann", b:"bnn", c: "1" }] so i get ["arr brr","arr brr","arr brr","ann, bnn"]

Answer (score 0):

Using Array constructor and `fill()` method can achieve with one line of code:

```js
const items = {a:"arr", b:"brr", c: "3"}
const arr = new Array(+items.c).fill(`${items.a} ${items.b}`)

console.log(arr)
```